# i want to clear a cell and then assign the value to it

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Clear_Table(ct)
    Range(ct).Select
    'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range(ct).Select
End Sub

Sub rite()



Clear_Table ("E10")

Range("E10").Value = "dwsds"

End Sub
```

> getting compile error: Argument not optional
>   (only want to clear value in a cell not the entire range and put the value in that cell. please help)

Comment: Agree with Vityata's point, but I cannot replicate your error. Perhaps you have other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that can do the job:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Clear_Table(ct As Range)

    ct.ClearContents

End Sub

Sub rite()

    Clear_Table Range("E10")
    Range("E10").Value = "dwsds"

End Sub
```

Try to avoid Selection as much as you can. See more here - [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/35864330#35864330)

Comment: Welcome, @DaulatDaga :) Feel free to accept the answer, once you can :)